# Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 - Visual Studio 2015 : Package failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 filed to install asp.net and web tools 2015

I tried more than one time also tried to repair Visual Studio i faced the same error.

also i tried to install the same ISO file on another machine and it worked fine

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem. how do I install it manually? what are these tools?

Comment: Me too. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: For ISO installations: I ended up "Changing" the installation under "Programs and Features" and picked the package in question to be installed.  The installer sat there for a while and then prompted me with three options, one of which was to point at the correct file.  I chose that and pointed at: ...ISO\VS2015_ENT_ENU\packages\WPT\webtoolsextensionsvs14.msi  Why the installer was unable to find the package on it's own does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

What a ridiculous ordeal. I was finally able to resolve this error by manually installing the `webtoolsextensionsvs14.msi` using msiexec and specifying a targetdir of `c:\temp`. For some reason is was trying to create temp install files directly in `c:\`

`msiexec /a webtoolsextensionsvs14.msi /qb /l* log.txt SKIP_SETUP=1 TARGETDIR=
c:\temp`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this. I will try to help you resolve this and do have a few questions.

1. Was this a clean installation or did you upgrade from a previous release such as RC?
2. Have you tried to repair Visual Studio?
3. Would you be able to share the installation logs? There should be two log files in your %temp% folder. The first file is an overall summary of the VS installation and should be have a name such as vs_professional_yyyymmddhhmmss.LOG. The second log is for the Web Tools package itself and should have a name such as vs_professional_yyyymmddhhmmss_nnn_WebToolsExtensionsVS14_1040.LOG

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: I have the same problem and is a clean install. I installed windows 10 right after I install visual studio 2015 community free and encountered this problem. What are the tools to install?